# Fixed marginpars with gray background in KOMA-Script

Tags: color, positioning, koma-script, marginpar, backgrounds

I am an newbie looking to achieve a sort of two column effect with my LaTeX report - I am using LaTeX `KOMA-script` as a base.

I want my margin to appear in a different background color, (say) gray, and main text background is (say) blue and I want to put images, text, graphs and equations in this margin. These contents are synched with particular paragraphs, i.e. I don't want them floating around, just fixed with respect to particular paragraphs in the main text.
So, how can I solve these two conditions?

Again,

1. Different background color for main text and the margin contents. (See Similar questions panel in tex.stackexchange.com website)
2. Make the contents of the margin par stay fixed with respect to the paragraphs of main text.

I have tried using a background image of two colors and stretching it across the entire page, but the effect is horrific... it does not align well with the main text and margins.

Any suggestions are really welcome.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: Could you specify "(See Similar questions panel in tex.stackexchange.com website)"? As it stands, it's not really a helpful piece of information.

Comment: Do it a in simple way by employing the parcolumns package, including the pdfcolparcolumns package. Sorry, I've got no time to elaborate, but this seems a simple solution to me.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the suggestions. To make it more elaborate, I just uploaded a picture of the template that i was trying to "copy" . ![see-the-snapshot](http://i40.tinypic.com/14lavm.png").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The color problem may be solved using [eso-pic](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic). Figures at the margin but not moving up or down may be done using [marginnote](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic). But sometimes moving would be recommended, so you should have a look at [marginfix](http://ctan.org/pkg/marginfix) too. Here an example with even some more colors than asked for:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}% You may use any other KOMA-Script class or
                       % e.g. a standard class.

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}% for demo only

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% remove option `demo' at real life
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}% to have colors (see http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor)
\usepackage{eso-pic}% put things into background (see http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic)
\usepackage{marginnote}% non floating margin notes (see http://ctan.org/pkg/marginnote)

\AddToShipoutPicture{% from package eso-pic: put something to the background
  % 1. Background
  \AtPageLowerLeft{% put it at the left bottom of the page
    \color{LightGrey}\rule{\LenToUnit\paperwidth}{\LenToUnit\paperheight}%
  }%
  % 2. Headline
  \AtTextUpperLeft{% put it at the left top of the text area
    \put(0,\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\headsep-\dp\strutbox\relax}){% move it up
      \color{BurlyWood}\rule{\LenToUnit\textwidth}{\LenToUnit\headheight}%
    }%
  }%
  % 3. Text area
  \AtTextLowerLeft{% put it at the left bottom of the text area
    \color{LightSkyBlue}\rule{\LenToUnit\textwidth}{\LenToUnit\textheight}%
  }%
  % 4. Bottom
  \AtTextLowerLeft{% put it at the left bottom of the text area
    \put(0,\LenToUnit{\dimexpr-\footskip-\dp\strutbox\relax}){% move it down
      % Note: While there is no \footheight, I'm using \headheight here.
      \color{BurlyWood}\rule{\LenToUnit\textwidth}{\LenToUnit\headheight}%
    }%
  }%
}

\setcapindent{0pt}% The margin is too small for hanging captions.

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\blindtext\marginnote{%
  \begin{minipage}{\marginparwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=5\baselineskip]{Test}\\
    \captionof{figure}{\hspace{0pt}Example figure}
  \end{minipage}
}

\blindtext

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Maybe using option `mpinclude` would be a good idea, if you have a lot of material at the margin (see [KOMA-Script manual scrguien.pdf](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)) for more information about this option). In this case, increasing `\marginparwidth` may or may not be a good idea.

If you would like to use text area + margin area for a figure or equation, you may use something like

```
\begin{addmargin*}[0pt]{\dimexpr \marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}
\begin{equation}
  f(x)=x^2
\end{equation}
\end{addmargin*}
```

`addmargin` and `addmargin*` are KOMA-Script environments. You may find them at the KOMA-Script manual.

I've used `\dimexpr` for some calculations at my example. You may find this at the [e-TeX manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/e-tex/v2/doc/etex_man.pdf). An alternative would be to use package [calc](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc). To avoid all the `\LenToUnit` you may simply use package [picture](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc). Package `picture` extends LaTeX's `picture` environment and you may use lengths instead of numbers at `\put`, `\makebox`, `\framebox` etc.

Comment: Excellent. Just compiled it and looks quite similar to what i wanted. My heartfelt thanks.

Comment: @Asif: In this case it would be nice, if you'd mark my answer to be the accepted answer.

Comment: The Colors are proper, although a bit misaligned to the text. However the margin image is not visible at all. Should I resize the margin or the image?

Comment: In the Koma-SCript that I am using the margins are set specifically.. could this be the reason for misalignment\usepackage{vmargin} > \setpapersize{A4} >

Comment: @Asif: I would not recommend using `vmargin` (e.g. it manipulates `\hoffset` and `\voffset` but does not handle `\marinparwidth`). Try `geometry` instead. `geometry` has a key to set `\marginparwidth`. BTW: Don't forget to remove option `demo` loading `graphicx` package!