# How to set colored ruled margins for different pages?

Tags: header-footer, margins

I want to write a LaTeX document, and I want to have document rules (colored margins distinguishing sections and/or even/odd pages).

Here is a model of what I have in mind:

[image: Page preview for final document]

How can this be accomplished?

I have seen [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7725/how-to-set-a-certain-color-other-than-white-to-margin-areas) which is the most relevant question to what I have in mind, however it doesn't quite accomplish my goal.

I have also searched around in Google, and the best I have come up with is used "framed" package, which again, does not accomplish this task. I am sure that this can be done, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a possible solution based on the following packages:

- [`tikzpagenodes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes)
- [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background)

Notice that two compilation runs are necessary to successfully color the margins.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[contents={},opacity=1,scale=1.485]{background}

\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}%
{\backgroundsetup{angle=0,position={0.9\textwidth,-
.7\textheight},%
contents={\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{ %
\coordinate (x) at (current page marginpar area.south east|-current page.south east);
\draw[draw=none,fill=magenta!20]([xshift=-\textwidth]x)rectangle(current page.north west);}}}}%
{\backgroundsetup{angle=0,position={0.9\textwidth,-
.7\textheight},%
contents={\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{ %
\coordinate (x) at (current page marginpar area.south east|-current page.south east);
\draw[draw=none,fill=orange!20](x)rectangle(current page.north east);}}}}%
\BgMaterial}

\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

Result (just the first two pages are displayed):

[image]

Comment: When I run LaTeX, I get "/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/background/background.sty:68: LaTeX Error: Unknown option `opacity=1' for package `background'." I am using MacTeX 2012, and running xelatex.

Comment: @MiladNaseri I don't get any errors with Claudio's code (I am using TeX Live2012) using pdflatex or xelatex. Are you getting this error with the *exact* code he posted?

Comment: @MiladNaseri: I also tried to compile my example with xelatex, but I don't have any errors. Is you MacTeX updated?

Answer (score 13):

I think the `tikz` solution is great, and probably allows for lots of complicated patterns, but if you just want a simple bar then there's no need for it.

The solution below uses:

- [`xcolor`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/xcolor) for colour
- [`eso-pic`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/eso-pic) for the backgrounds on each page (which is required for the [`background`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/background) package)
- [`ifthen`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/ifthen) for conditionals

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}                 % to have colors 
\usepackage{eso-pic}                % put things into background 
\usepackage{lipsum}                 % for sample text
\usepackage{ifthen}

\AddToShipoutPicture{% from package eso-pic: put something to the background
    \ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}{
          % ODD page: left bar
          \AtPageLowerLeft{% start the bar at the left bottom of the page
                \color{blue}\rule{2cm}{\LenToUnit\paperheight}%
          }%
      }%
      {%
          % EVEN page: right bar
          \AtPageLowerLeft{% start the bar at the bottom right of the page
              \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperwidth-3cm},0){% move it to the top right
                  \color{orange}\rule{3cm}{\LenToUnit\paperheight}%
                }%
           }%
       }%
}


\begin{document}
\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Here's a useful reference for the future:

[Fixed marginpars with gray background in KOMA-Script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35111/fixed-marginpars-with-gray-background-in-koma-script)

Answer (score 13):

No answers with `fancyhdr` and `tikz`!. Let me jump in:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}               % you know what this does!
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}             % put things headers and footers and we plan misuse it ;)
\usepackage{lipsum}               % for sample text


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \fill [color=blue]
        (current page.north west)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south west) + (1cm,0cm) $);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\fancyhead[RE]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \fill [color=orange]  
        (current page.north east)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-1cm,0cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]