# Lilypond generated with MuseScore does not fit the width of the page in XeTeX doc

Tags: graphics, xetex, width, lilypond

I am using MuseScore 1.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 to write my scores. Then I save them as LilyPond files, and include them in my tex document using `\lilypondfile`, like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

Larger examples can be put into a separate file, and introduced with \verb+\lilypondfile+.

\lilypondfile[quote,noindent]{scores/Exercise_1.05.ly}

\end{document}
```

Then, to compile, I do:

```
$ lilypond-book --pdf solfeo.lytex
$ xelatex solfeo.tex
```

However, the width of the inserted score doesn't fit into the document, and it extends beyond the limits of the page.

[image: Screenshot of a score that doesn't fit]

Also, `lilypond-book` seems to be ignoring the settings I am passing to it in `\lilypondfile[quote,noindent]{scores/Exercise_1.05.ly}`. If I understood well, `quote` prints the notes before the score and `noindent` removes the indentation of the first line. Neither it is quoting the notes nor is it removing the indentation.

I'm new to Lilypond and I have tried to change the margins of the document in MuseScore, and I tried some tex commands too, but I can't find the way to make it fit. If I compile the ly file with `lilypond` the PDF looks perfect (but in that case I only get the score). Its only when I embed a `ly` file into a `lytex` file that the score extends beyond the margins. Would appreciate your suggestions or corrections. ¿What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

P.D. Here is the ly code generated by MuseScore:

```
%=============================================
%   created by MuseScore Version: 1.3
%=============================================

\version "2.12.0"



#(set-default-paper-size "a4")

\paper {
  line-width    = 190\mm
  left-margin   = 10\mm
  top-margin    = 10\mm
  bottom-margin = 20\mm
  %%indent = 0 \mm 
  %%set to ##t if your score is less than one page: 
  ragged-last-bottom = ##t 
  ragged-bottom = ##f  
  %% in orchestral scores you probably want the two bold slashes 
  %% separating the systems: so uncomment the following line: 
  %% system-separator-markup = \slashSeparator 
  }

\header {
    }

AvoiceAA = \relative c'{
    \set Staff.instrumentName = #""
    \set Staff.shortInstrumentName = #""
    \clef treble
    %staffkeysig
    \key c \major 
    %barkeysig: 
    \key c \major 
    %bartimesig: 
    \time 4/4 
    \tempo "Andante" 4 = 96  a'2 a      | % 1
    a r      | % 2
    r a      | % 3
    r a      | % 4
    a r      | % 5
    a a      | % 6
    a a4 a      | % 7
    a r a2      | % 8
    r4 a a2      | % 9
    a4 r2 a4      | % 10
    a2 r4 a \bar "|."     | % 11
    a2 r \bar "|." 
}% end of last bar in partorvoice


\score { 
    << 
        \context Staff = ApartA << 
            \context Voice = AvoiceAA \AvoiceAA
        >>




      \set Score.skipBars = ##t
      %%\set Score.melismaBusyProperties = #'()
      \override Score.BarNumber #'break-visibility = #end-of-line-invisible
     %%every bar is numbered.!!!
      %% remove previous line to get barnumbers only at beginning of system.
       #(set-accidental-style 'modern-cautionary)
      \set Score.markFormatter = #format-mark-box-letters %%boxed rehearsal-marks
       \override Score.TimeSignature #'style = #'() %%makes timesigs always numerical
      %% remove previous line to get cut-time/alla breve or common time 
      \set Score.pedalSustainStyle = #'mixed 
       %% make spanners comprise the note it end on, so that there is no doubt that this note is included.
       \override Score.TrillSpanner #'(bound-details right padding) = #-2
      \override Score.TextSpanner #'(bound-details right padding) = #-1
      %% Lilypond's normal textspanners are too weak:  
      \override Score.TextSpanner #'dash-period = #1
      \override Score.TextSpanner #'dash-fraction = #0.5
      %% lilypond chordname font, like mscore jazzfont, is both far too big and extremely ugly (olagunde@start.no):
      \override Score.ChordName #'font-family = #'roman 
      \override Score.ChordName #'font-size =#0 
      %% In my experience the normal thing in printed scores is maj7 and not the triangle. (olagunde):
      \set Score.majorSevenSymbol = \markup {maj7}
  >>

  %% Boosey and Hawkes, and Peters, have barlines spanning all staff-groups in a score,
  %% Eulenburg and Philharmonia, like Lilypond, have no barlines between staffgroups.
  %% If you want the Eulenburg/Lilypond style, comment out the following line:
  \layout {\context {\Score \consists Span_bar_engraver}}
}%% end of score-block 

#(set-global-staff-size 20)
```

## Update 1

I'm pasting the output of the compilation of `lilypond-book`, although I'm not sure how useful it will be for you, since it it in Spanish:

```
$ lilypond-book --pdf solfeo.lytex

lilypond-book (GNU LilyPond) 2.18.2
Reading solfeo.lytex...
Running `pdflatex' on file `/tmp/tmpN3IGhy.tex' to detect default page settings.

Dissecting...
Writing snippets...
Processing...
Running lilypond...
GNU LilyPond 2.18.2
Procesando «snippet-map-3001632500490555250.ly»
Analizando...
Procesando «solfeo.lytex»
Analizando...
Renombrando la entrada a: «scores/Exercise_1.05.ly»
Interpretando la música...[8]
Preprocesando los objetos gráficos...
Calculando los saltos de línea... 
Dibujando los sistemas... 
Salida de la página hacia «ba/lily-399811ac.eps»...
Convirtiendo en «ba/lily-399811ac.pdf»...
Salida de la página hacia «ba/lily-399811ac-1.eps»...
Salida de la página hacia «ba/lily-399811ac-2.eps»...
Convirtiendo en «ba/lily-399811ac-1.pdf»...
Convirtiendo en «ba/lily-399811ac-2.pdf»...
Escribiendo «ba/lily-399811ac-systems.texi»...
Escribiendo «ba/lily-399811ac-systems.tex»...
Escribiendo «ba/lily-399811ac-systems.count»...
Enhorabuena. La compilación se ha completado satisfactoriamente.
Linking files...
Compiling /media/admin/DATOS/Dropbox/code/solfeo-book/out/solfeo.tex...
Writing `/media/admin/DATOS/Dropbox/code/solfeo-book/out/solfeo.tex'...
```

I hope this helps

## Update 2

I have tried another approach. I have exported from MuseScore to MusicXML instead. Then I have used:

`musicxml2ly Exercise_1.05.xml -o Exercise_1.05_.ly`

to convert the `.xml` file into an `.ly` file, and compiled again. Still the width is not fitting the screen =( I have run out of ideas.

Comment: How many times did you compile?

Comment: @Aradnix several, why?

Comment: While I don't think it's a problem here, there are many cases where repeat runs of `latex` are needed to sort out positioning issues.  When the document is processed, auxiliary information is written out to be included in the next run.  This sometimes takes time to stabilize.

Comment: @SeanAllred Yeah, I'm familiar with that, but it happens when you have things like indexes, or ToCs, and the like, because it needs the several runs to build the tables. Anyway, I have run XeLaTeX several times but still the width is bigger than the document... The call to insert the score is even ignoring the options I pass it (`quote`, `noindent`), so I don't know what else to do :-(

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the resources to troubleshoot the actual problem here at work, but I will note for your information that you can have non-index related things that need multiple compiles, too :) http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155488/17423

Comment: How committed are you to using `lilypond-book`? If you use the EPS backend of `lilypond` you can produce a cropped PDF image that is exactly the width you specify (ideally your LaTeX `\textwidth`, I imagine), and then include the PDF using `\includegraphics`. I have found this to be the simplest way.

Comment: @SeanAllred Thank you Sean, your effort is appreciated. Great layout by the way! (the one in your link)

Comment: @AndrewCashner I really don't know yet which will be the easiest workflow. I want to write the scores only once (preferably in MuseScore, which is more user-friendly), and then export them to a format that is good for both LaTeX and the web, since I will be working on a blog + book. My initial idea was: Export from MuseScore to ly to use in LaTeX, and embed from MuseScore in the blog posts with Play options out of the box. I could produce a PNG,  EPS or PDF image directly from MuseScore, but I want to typeset the music in the TeX for better quality. I also don't always have huge scores.

Comment: @AndrewCashner For example, sometimes I have small examples or exercises that are not more than 1 or 2 lines. If I embed those with `\includegraphics` or `\includepdf`, it will include them in a separate page as a block, but sometimes I want them to be inline.

Comment: @XiruxNefer Because before read the awesome answer of Andrew Cashner I thought it could be a trouble similar with the TOC and title page I have sometimes when I compile a file with some class for first time, when in the second or third fits better. Now I see I was wrong and the mistake was different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`lilypond-book` is just a complicated way of producing cropped PDF images of each of your examples and then automatically including them in a LaTeX file.

You can do the same thing by hand, in my opinion much more simply, by using the EPS backend of `lilypond` to produce an image cropped to the size of the music.

Then the only real LaTeX component is to include the PDF images using the `graphicx` package. **The main point is that you can set the width of the image in the `lilypond` source and then just include it at its natural size in the LaTeX document.**

In the example below, you can `\include` the `example.ly` file in all your music example `.ly` source files, and when compiled they will produce cropped PDFs.

---

Three files for this example:

- 1. `example.ly` -- Page layout for cropped musical examples in `lilypond`
- 2. `score.ly` -- Your musical example, which `\includes` the page layout commands from `example.ly`
- 3. `analysis.tex` -- Sample TeX file showing how the image is included.

---

FILE 1, `example.ly`

```
% STYLE SHEET FOR IN-TEXT EXAMPLES

\version "2.18.2"

#( ly:set-option 'backend 'eps )

\paper{
  indent = 0.75\in
  line-width = 6.5\in
    top-margin = 1\in
    bottom-margin = 2\in
    ragged-bottom = ##t
    ragged-last-bottom = ##t
  oddFooterMarkup=##f
  oddHeaderMarkup=##f
  bookTitleMarkup = ##f
  scoreTitleMarkup = ##f
}
```

---

FILE 2 -- `score.ly`

```
\version "2.18.2"
\include "example.ly"

Music = { 
    \clef "tenor"
    \time 3/4
    c4 d4 e4 |
    f2 g4~ |
    g4 a2 |
    b2. |
    c'2. |
    \bar "||"
}

\score{
    <<
        \new Staff { \Music }
    >>
    \layout {}
}
```

---

FILE 3 - `analysis.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Music Example}

\lipsum[1]
See example~\ref{fig:score1}.

%*******************
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{score}\centering
\caption{Score example 1}
\label{fig:score1}
\end{figure}
%*******************

\lipsum[2]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your example is amazing! Indeed it solves the problem of the width. However, there's no way to tell MuseScore to produce a separate ly file just for the page layout :-( Since I'll be producing tons of small inline examples as well as scores of several pages, editing then manually isn't a practical option.I'll keep your solution in mind, anyway. I want to avoid exporting from MuseScore to PNG because I want the notes correctly typeset in LaTeX. I also want to avoid creating the score once in MuseScore and then again in ly.There must be a way to export from MuseScore that's LaTeX & web friendly

Comment: I don't know how MuseScore export works, but it does seem like you could edit the exported `.ly` files to add the `\include` line. It's a bit cumbersome, but everything with `lilypond` is (to be frank).

Comment: Note that LaTeX does not *typeset* `lilypond` output. `Lilypond` just makes a PDF or other image and LaTeX includes it, just like a drawing from Inkscape. All the text in `lilypond` like lyric or instrument names is rendered by `lilypond` using Pango (etc.) and the TeX engine does not alter it. So you have to work to keep fonts looking the same (I use `libertine` on both sides and it looks good).

Comment: Looks like just adding `ragged-right` to the list of options in `\lilypondfile[quote,noindent,ragged-right]{scores/Exercise_1.05.ly}` made the trick! Oh my, I've been working on this for 3 days... I think I'm going to bed now.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out! Since that is actually the answer to your question, you could post it as an answer and then accept that one instead. I hope my answer is helpful to someone, but I realize it wasn't quite what you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

Old question I know, but I was looking for a solution today so I guess still relevant.  Here is the solution I am using, I simply put this in the preamble of my document.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
```

This works because under the hood what is being use is `\includegraphics` and I just set the default width of those images to the width of a line so it never overflows the page.