# header-footer and box

Tags: header-footer, boxes

I am mostly new to Latex. I was looking for a template which I like. The problem is I don't know how to obtain that. Here is one. This one looks very challenging for a new one like me. I will really appreciate any suggestion. [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{changepage,lipsum,titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{underscore} % Allows literal underscores
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % Allows \textsubscript{}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz} % For diagrams
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % For headers and footers
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

 \geometry{
 a4paper, % Change this if you intend to print on a different paper size, such as letter paper.
 total={210mm,297mm},
 left=20mm,
 right=20mm,
 top=30mm,
 bottom=30mm,
 }
\pagestyle{fancy}

%Settings
\newcommand{\courseName}{COURSE101} % Insert course name here
\title{\courseName: Unit 1}
\author{Your name}
\date{} % If you'd like to have a date, place it here

% Headers and footers. See documentation for 'fancyhdr' package for more information.
\lhead{\courseName} % Left header
\chead{} % Center header
\rhead{} % Right header
\lfoot{} % Left footer
\cfoot{\thepage} % Center footer
\rfoot{} % Right footer

% Lecture block settings.
\lstset{
  basicstyle= \normalfont,
  mathescape=true, % Allows for adding equations.
  escapechar={~}, % You may wish to change this symbol, if you use ~ in your notes a lot.
  breaklines=true, % Automatic text wrapping.
  columns=fullflexible
}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{ppl} %Set font

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\section*{Example lecture block}
\begin{lstlisting}
Main bullet point
    Sub-point (use tabs)
    Enclose regular LaTeX with the ~\textasciitilde{}~ (tilde) symbol: ~\LaTeX~
    Enclose math with the ~\$~ symbol: $ \frac{1}{2} $
\end{lstlisting}

% For each lecture/session/workshop, use one of these blank \section and lstlisting blocks
\section*{Lecture title}
\begin{lstlisting}

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Flowfram comes to mind.  Also everypage and tikzpagenodes.

Comment: I beleive this is done here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153736/reproduction-of-word-report-template-in-latex