# I'd like to fill my page margins with art. How can I go about doing that?

Tags: margins

I am guessing TikZ is going to be involved somewhere in the answer, but I may also want to put in images I created in other software into the page margins. How might I go about doing something like this in general?

`pstricks` looks like a great starting point: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29805/49339

Comment: Probably the `background`, `tikzpagenodes` package etc. Examples: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103314/10898

Comment: I would start by browsing examples on this site and others. See how they are coded. Decide what exactly you want to do: do you want to learn TiKZ? pstricks? to include external images? Right now, the question is really not answerable: there are a whole bunch of ways you might go about it, depending on what you actually want to do.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends?lq=1, http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/, https://www.tug.org/texshowcase/...