# Add background colour to margin notes area

Tags: color, marginnote

I want to delimit margin note area by a **background color for all the document** like in some nice books.

I tried with `marginnote` and `todonote` packages without success.

You are my last hope...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you mean you want to have a colored band on every page?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I think you can check if the answers to [How to set colored ruled margins for different pages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73480/13304) are of help for you.

Answer (score 7):

This is a job for the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) and [`tikzpagenodes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) packages:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
contents={\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\fill[red!30] (current page marginpar area.north west) rectangle (current page marginpar area.south east);
}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The code needs two or three runs to stabilize.