# Make dotfill on left page

Tags: tikz-pgf, fancyhdr, marginnote

[image]

Please help me code the left dots for note.
They are repeated on all pages.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: See, for example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140514/handwriting-drill-sheets, for techniques to lay lines (or dotted lines) underneath of areas intended for text.

Answer (score 2):

The best I can get:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=7cm,right=1cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1cm,footskip=0.6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \Repeat \prg_replicate:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\mydotfill}{\dotfill\par}

\begin{document}
\begin{textblock*}{5.5cm}(1cm,1.5cm+2.5pt)
\noindent\parbox[c]{5.5cm}{
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node at (0,0) [anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] {\parbox[c]{\textwidth}{\color{green!70!blue}\large\Repeat{40}{\mydotfill}}};
\setlength{\parindent}{20pt}\large
This is the side dot fill area. Write what ever you want.

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{center}

\lipsum[2]
}
\end{textblock*}
\noindent\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node at (0,0) [anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] {\parbox[c]{\textwidth}{\color{green!70!blue}\large\Repeat{40}{\mydotfill}}};
\large This is main dot fill area. Write what ever you want.

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{center}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
I found that the below code can be modified for this pupose. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118792/add-background-colour-to-margin-notes-area?fbclid=IwAR3CL2b0ZVE4EV_q4X6nko1RZok2wFKgRfIWLFp4k2gMCRGP3aQkXlrqTKI