# etoolbox instead of ifthen

Tags: etoolbox, xifthen

I try to realize [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126156/101831) with `etoolbox` instead of `ifthen`.

**What I have so far...**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[contents={},opacity=1,scale=1.485]{background}

\newtoggle{BgMat}
\settoggle{BgMat}{true}

\AddEverypageHook{%
  \iftoggle{BgMat}{%
    \ifboolexpe{\isodd{\thepage}}%
    {\backgroundsetup{angle=0,position={0.9\textwidth,-
    .7\textheight},%
    contents={\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{ %
    \coordinate (x) at (current page marginpar area.south east|-current page.south east);
    \draw[draw=none,fill=magenta!20]([xshift=-\textwidth]x)rectangle(current page.north west);}}}}%
    {\backgroundsetup{angle=0,position={0.9\textwidth,-
    .7\textheight},%
    contents={\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{ %
    \coordinate (x) at (current page marginpar area.south east|-current page.south east);
    \draw[draw=none,fill=orange!20](x)rectangle(current page.north east);}}}}%
    \BgMaterial
  }{%
  }
}

\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-8]

\clearpage
\settoggle{BgMat}{false}% deactivate colored margins
\lipsum[1-8]

\clearpage
\settoggle{BgMat}{true}% activate colored margins
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

Comment: What’s the problem?

Comment: @gigabytes: It does not compile, that seems the problem, but the O.P. forgot to mention it  ;-)

Comment: From a quick view point I don't see any need for `etoolbox` here at all (Well, I used it also some years ago before I started to learn about `\newif` etc.

Comment: Especially, `\thepage` is not necessarily a literal number (think of roman figures!), so `\isodd` might fail

Comment: A side note: There is no `\isodd` macro in `etoolbox`. You meant `\ifnumodd`, must likely

Comment: Most likely, of course ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution without `etoolbox` features, just traditional `\newif` and `\ifodd`.

Please do not use `\isodd{\thepage}` etc. → `\thepage` can expand to 'anything', so `\isodd` as test for odd numbers might fail. If you want the literal numeric value of a counter named, say foo, use `\value{foo}`

And I learned from reading `etoolbox`, that there is no `\isodd` macro, the macro is called `\ifnumodd`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage[contents={},opacity=1,scale=1.485]{background}


\newif\ifBGMat

\BGMattrue

\AddEverypageHook{%
  \ifBGMat
  \ifodd\value{page} \backgroundsetup{angle=0,position={0.9\textwidth,-.7\textheight},
    contents={\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{ %
        \coordinate (x) at (current page marginpar area.south east|-current page.south east);
        \draw[draw=none,fill=magenta!20]([xshift=-\textwidth]x)rectangle(current page.north west);}}}
  \else
  \backgroundsetup{angle=0,position={0.9\textwidth,-.7\textheight},
    contents={\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{ %
        \coordinate (x) at (current page marginpar area.south east|-current page.south east);
        \draw[draw=none,fill=orange!20](x)rectangle(current page.north east);}}}
  \fi
  \fi
  \BgMaterial
 }



\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-8]

\clearpage
\BGMatfalse
\lipsum[1-8]

\clearpage
\BGMattrue
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I gladly recommend using `etoolbox` features rather than `\ifthen`. For instance, you can simplify your code using the fact that `\ifnumodd` is expandable.

Note `\value{page}` instead of `\thepage`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[contents={},opacity=1,scale=1.485]{background}

\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text

\newtoggle{BgMat}
\settoggle{BgMat}{true}

\AddEverypageHook{%
  \iftoggle{BgMat}
   {% BgMat true
    \backgroundsetup{
      angle=0,
      position={0.9\textwidth,-0.7\textheight},
      contents={\ifnumodd{\value{page}}{\BgPictureOdd}{\BgPictureEven}},
    }%
    \BgMaterial
   }
   {% BgMat false
   }%
}

\newcommand{\BgPictureOdd}{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{%
    \coordinate (x) at (current page marginpar area.south east|-current page.south east);
    \draw[draw=none,fill=magenta!20]([xshift=-\textwidth]x)rectangle(current page.north west);}%
}
\newcommand{\BgPictureEven}{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{%
    \coordinate (x) at (current page marginpar area.south east|-current page.south east);
    \draw[draw=none,fill=orange!20](x)rectangle(current page.north east);}%
}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-8]

\clearpage
\settoggle{BgMat}{false}% deactivate colored margins
\lipsum[1-8]

\clearpage
\settoggle{BgMat}{true}% activate colored margins
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

[image]