# Add a logo to tikz fancyhead and footer

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, fancyhdr, border, bclogo

USING OverLeaf

I would like to add a Logo at right top corner in the header. 1 cm from the right edge. And a text in the footer 1 cm from the left edge.
I tried using rhead. But I am very new to LaTex and this is ...too fancy for a newbie.
The blue border on the right has to stay.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{maxlink}{RGB}{2,60,180}
\usepackage{tikz}               % you know what this does!
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}         % put things headers and footers and we plan misuse it ;)
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,headheight=26pt,includeheadfoot]{geometry}

%\setlength\headheight{26pt} %% just to make warning go away. Adjust the value after looking into the warning.
%\rhead{{\color{blue}\rule{1cm}{1cm}}}

%\rhead{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{Max-Logo.png}}

%\rhead{\begin{picture}(3,3) 
%\put(3,3){\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}} 
%\end{picture}}

\fancypagestyle{mypage}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LO]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
            \fill [color=maxlink] (current page.north west) rectangle
                ($ (current page.south west) + (0.4cm,0cm) $);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{mypage}   % activate colored margins
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\mbox{}

\clearpage
%\pagestyle{mypage}   % activate colored margins
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\mbox{}

\end{document}
```

I don't have to use tikz and fancy head for the border, I just found this at 
[how-to-set-colored-ruled-margins-for-some-pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126155/how-to-set-colored-ruled-margins-for-some-pages.)

Comment: Can you please try to restructure your question to become clearer? Do you only want to include the graphics in the header or put the graphics at a predefined position relative to the page borders?

Comment: BTW, you are allowed to answer your own questions.  Also, I would have use everypage instead of fancyhdr.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I want the graphics in the header. So it repeats each page.

So a logo, in the header on the top left 1cm from the right edge.
And a footer that is 1cm from left edge.

I am trying to make a letter head template. The blue ribbon on the side needs to stay. And I need our company's logo on the top right. On all page.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks. I'll read up on that.